# Automate multiple regex Search/Replace queries in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, replace

I publish web articles for my company using Dreamweaver.  Currently I have about 10 fairly complex reg-ex search/replace queries that I have to run on every article to clean up various code mistakes that get entwined in the process (which I have no control over).  I run them on multiple files at a time to speed up the back-n-forth, but I still have to run each one separately.

Is there a way to batch-run multiple queries in Dreamweaver?

or

Can you combine queries to run at the same time with different replacement terms?  (Eg: If X = query1 then replace with Y, but if X = query 2 then replace with Z)

or

I'd rather do it in Dreamweaver, but is there a plugin or separate program that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use Notepad++ for this. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> command does the job.

Comment: I can do that in Dreamweaver, I need to run multiple in one swoop.

Comment: @QuietMan Ctrl+Shift+F in Notepad++ uses a glob and replaces in all files matched. You might want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I came across this from Google while looking to do a similar thing in Sharepoint Designer.

If its not too late for some advice, I would have a look at creating a custom command in Dreamweaver. I did have one years ago that a contractor wrote for me to combat a specific scenario. Basically it was a cleanup script that ran multiple RegEx in sequence, you could choose to run the command against, the current open file, selected docs, or the site.

It was really handy.